# A very cramped place with visiting aliens

Tags: story-identification, aliens, novella

I read this novella (or maybe longish novelette ?) at least 20 years ago, probably in a magazine so it could have been older than that.

I don't remember much. It took place in a crowded place, probably a space station. There was gravity there, they had staircases (see below). But since it was just there that aliens had made first contact, tourists from Earth came in crowds to see them and it became absolutely cramped. There are just two impressions that I remember. One is this crazily cramped situation, people renting one step of a staircase to sleep. The other is the rush, the urgency. I believe the main human protagonist was a woman, and she kept running from one place to another. Ah, yes, she spoke English, but the regulars of the station were mostly Japanese speakers. Hardship of communication with the aliens in both English and Japanese was one of the points of the story.

---

I have been trying to remember more. I think that the woman is the only POV character, but there were two more major protagonists (plus several other characters I don't remember much). One was one of the aliens, and the other one was a (human) man. For some reason the alien wanted to create a romantic relationship between the man and the woman, and IIRC, it worked out in the end.

- Note, this story is not *The Space Merchants*
- It is not *Guesting Time* either. There are just a few aliens. The crowding is due to tourists from Earth.

Comment: Renting steps on a staircase to sleep was featured in *The Space Merchants* but the rest doesn't fit that.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I read s synopsis of *The Space Merchants* It definitely is not it. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Your title reminds me of "Guesting Time" by R. A. Lafferty, but the visiting aliens in Lafferty's story are on Earth, not on a space station.